# fs.readFileSync("./bank/"+client,'cp1251'); is throwing throw new ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING

Tags: javascript, readfile, cp1251

I'm trying read from a file (The file is in Bulgarian) and with utf 8 it returns nonsense characters so I tried cp1251 but it throws: ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE_ENCODING.

```
var str = fs.readFileSync("./bank1/"+client,'cp1251');
```

Comment: Node.js has not supported cp1251 natively in the past. Supported natively are: ascii, base64, binary, hex, ucs2/ucs-2/utf16le/utf-16le, utf8/utf-8, and latin1. So you'll have to add a conversion library to cast the cyrillic to one of the above. Sidenote: The name can be  `windows-1251` or `win1251`, depending on the library, instead of `cp1251`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install iconv:

```
npm install iconv
```

Use the code to read file encoded in `cp1251`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
var iconv = new Iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8');
const encoded = fs.readFileSync("./bank1/"+client);
const decoded = iconv.convert(encoded).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the encoding option as an object like so:

```
var str = fs.readFileSync("./bank1/"+client, { encoding: 'cp1251' });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, problem is in value 'cp1251'. By the sources of lib available options are `type BufferEncoding = "ascii" | "utf8" | "utf-8" | "utf16le" | "ucs2" | "ucs-2" | "base64" | "latin1" | "binary" | "hex";`